# How to capture all matching groups between 2 particular patterns?

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm trying to extract properties of a unit test, written in a C# file.

I want to extract certain properties between 2 lines of code. The 2 lines are used to identify the correct method from the file and thus grab the right properties.

Following is an example string:

```
  {
        Assert.True(false, "hello");
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is the summary of the method.
    /// </summary>
    [Fact]
    [Trait("abc", "xyz")]
    [Trait("pqr", "stu")]
    [Trait("jkl", "mno")]
    [InlineData(abc)]
    [InlineData(xyz)]
    public async Task MethodName()
    {
      var abcd = wxyz;
      var tad = fun();
    }

    [Fact]
    [Trait("abcd", "x")]
    [Trait("p", "stu")]
    [Trait("jl", "m")]
    public async Task AnotherMethod()
    {
      blah blah
    }
```

I want to extract the key value pair of Traits above MethodName() only and not AnotherMethod(), i.e.

```
abc xyz 
pqr stu 
jkl mno
```

The properties like Traits and InlineData will always be between [Fact] or [Theory] and MethodName().

I tried the following regex:

```
(?:(\[Fact\]|\[Theory\])[\s\S]*?\[Trait\(\"([^"]*)\", ?\"([^"]*)\"\)\][\s\S]+?MethodName\()
```

This regex only matches the first Trait returning abc and xyz. Below is the output.

[image]

When using the regex just to match the Traits, without any following pattern, It returns the correct output:

[image]

Is there something I'm missing?
Also,
How can I also extract the summary text, given that it is optional and might not be there for alot of methods..?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simpler solution:
`\"(\w+)\"`

[image: regex101]

If you need only three-letters words, you can modify pattern:

`\"(\w{3})\"`

You can use perfect resource to train pattern [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

This pattern will find key in group 1 and value in group 2:

`\"(\w{3})\".\s\"(\w{3})\"`

[image: second pattern]

This pattern will catch only 3-letters words:

`\b\w{3}\b`

[image: pic3]

... and capture that you don't need. Then add some conditions in pattern:

`\"\b\w{3}\b\"`

But you need to test it anyway in a lot of cases. First of all you can use brackets to indicate regex to capture only construct in the brackets (pic no 1). Outside the brackets you can add parameters to search. Regex have two cases of matching: Match and Group. And in a lot of cases you should group your search results. I don't know where you will use the regex, but in python it will be as proper `.group(num of group)`

And to group only "abc" (without commas): `\"(\b\w+\b)\"`

It is crazy...

`\s\[Trait\(\"(\w+)\".\s\"(\w+)\"\)\]\s+\s\[Trait\(\"(\w+)\".\s\"(\w+)\"\)\]\s+\s\[Trait\(\"(\w+)\".\s\"(\w+)\"\)\]\s+(?:public async Task MainMethod\(\))`

[image: crazy]

Comment: Yeah I'm able to match this pattern as you can see in the 2nd picture I've attached. However I'd like to match the Trait pair between 2 patterns. For example, all pairs between Fact and MethodName(). As soon as I do that, it only matches one pair

Comment: Let me note: you want to extract abc, xyz and other? Show please in question what do you want to see in output

Comment: Have a look at my first regex and the first picture. I want to extract only abc,xyz and other, that lie between the lines of MethodName() and [Fact]

Comment: Consider that there are alot more traits and functions in this file. I have to only extract ones that match a particular Method Name

Comment: I've updated the question a bit. Maybe my phrasing didn't explain my query correctly. Have a look at my test string at the top of my question. There are multiple methods and I want to extract only the Traits above MethodName(). Extracting the key value pair on its own isn;t the problem. The problem is that as soon as I put a pattern for MethodName(), it only matches one of the Trait key value pair above MethodName()

Comment: Also, key value pair could be anything with any number of letters. However, that's not the main concern..

Comment: Is the last edit was helpful for you?

Comment: You've got my query now. But unfortunately this solution isn't helpful. I'm not aware of the number of Traits I might have.. Even I've been looking for it in and out and trying to figure out why it won't grab all the Trait key value pairs..

Comment: Can you capture just everything between AnotherMethod() and its adjacent Fact? The output should not include properties of MainMethod(). Just the ones above AnotherMethod()...? Even that would somewhat help me. Won't solve my query but yeah

Comment: Of course you can catch it by this: `\[([\w\s\S]+)(?:public async Task MainMethod\(\))` and then you can find inside that you need by patterns above

Comment: Try the same for AnotherMethod() in the test string once, it captures everything above that. How do I make it not do that..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247357/discussion-between-vovakirdan-and-chaitanya-malik).