# How to Non-Greedily match a pattern in a multi-line input?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

I'm trying to create a single regex for printing lines between two patterns. I need it to be non-greedy, though.

Below is the dummy C# input file.

```
/// <summary>
/// This is a comment
/// </summary>
[Fact]
[Trait("a", "b")]
[InlineData(cd)]
public async Task TestOne()
{
\\ lines of code
}

[Theory]
[Trait("ab", "cd")]
[Trait("ef", "ghi")]
[InlineData(jkl)]
[InlineData(mnop)]
public async Task TestTwo(string hello)
{
\\ lines of code
}

/// <summary>
/// This is a comment
/// </summary>
[Theory]
[Trait("ab", "cd")]
[Trait("ef", "ghi")]
public async Task TestThree(bye)
{
\\ lines of code
}

/// <summary>
/// This is a comment
/// </summary>
[Fact]
[Trait("ab", "cd")]
[Trait("ef", "ghi")]
[InlineData(jkl)]
[InlineData(mnop)]
public async Task TestFour(string hello)
{
\\ lines of code
}

[Theory]
public async Task TestFive()
{
\\ lines of code
}
```

What I want to be printed are the lines between "TestTwo()" and its nearest preceding "[Fact]" or "[Theory]". And ONLY those lines. That is, I want the following printed:

```
[Theory]
[Trait("ab", "cd")]
[Trait("ef", "ghi")]
[InlineData(jkl)]
[InlineData(mnop)]
public async Task TestTwo(string hello)
```

I also do not want to match for a specific number of lines, as the line count will fluctuate. Test() may or may not have parameters.

I'm implementing this using bash script, so any single liner bash method would also help. A simple regex would also be more than sufficient.

I've tried alot of things and achieving this is kind of a compromise for what I actually wanted to achieve using a one liner regex.

Do give a look at the following question as well if you can!

[How to capture all matching groups between 2 particular patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73383549/how-to-capture-all-matching-groups-between-2-particular-patterns/73383688?noredirect=1#comment129601669_73383688)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot do what you ask for with a single regexp in awk or sed. If it's doable with grep it'd have to be using GNU grep with `-P` and `-z` (which the man page describes as an experimental combination so YMMV) plus other options but even then I doubt it's possible and if it was possible it'd be nightmarish incantation of runes. Why not just ask for help creating a concise, robust script to produce the output you want instead?

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If blank line is not always always present between each text block then following `gnu-awk` solution should work:

```bash
awk -v RS='\\[(Fact|Theory)]\n' '
match($0, /(.* TestTwo *\([^\n]+).+/, a) {
   print hdr a[1]
}
{hdr = RT}
' file.cpp

[Theory]
[Trait("ab", "cd")]
[Trait("ef", "ghi")]
[InlineData(jkl)]
[InlineData(mnop)]
public async Task TestTwo(string hello)
```

Here:

- `-v RS='\\[(Fact|Theory)]\n'` sets record separator as `[Fact]` or `[Theory]` and line break
- `RT` contains the text matched by `RS` regex
- `match` function uses a capture group to match what we need to keep

---

Here is a `gnu-grep` solution to do the same:

```bash
grep -oPz '(?sm)(?>^//[^\n]+\n)*\[(?>Fact|Theory)]\n(?>(?!\[(?>Fact|Theory)]\n).)*TestTwo[^\n]+\n' file.cpp
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bBGVMP/2)

Comment: Hey @anubhava, That works like a charm if we consider all blocks are seperated by a blank line... That might be the case in most blocks but this isn't a defined pattern in the file. Some blocks may not be seperated by a blank line. The defined pattern, that will match for all the blocks/tests is the one I specified.. The lines between [Fact] and TestName... Thanks for the answer tho!

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks alot for that. I'll mark this the right answer. Can you just help me with one little thing as well.. I didn't specify this in the question as I thought these were minor changes and I'll implement them on my own. But I'm not very familiar with awk. Can you help with those?

Comment: The [Fact] part could either be [Fact] or [Theory], not both. And TestTwo() might also contain some functional parameters, For example, TestTwo(abcd). The parameter might or might not be there...

Comment: I've edited the input text in y question, if that helps..

Comment: Works perfectly! However, I am facing a little abnormality in my real file where I search for the Test with Theory on top of it. And the output replaces the Theory with Fact. This happens for just one method and is working perfectly for the others.. Do you have any idea why this might be happening?
Also, thanks alot for the help! Much appreciated..

Comment: Works now! (Tried with grep) Sorry to keep bothering you with this but I just had one last thing. This isn't a necessity but I was wondering if this was possible.... I've updated the input string in the question. Notice the <summary> section. This may or may not be present right above a [Fact] or a [Theory] for a particular test.. Is there any way I can also match this pattern? Only if it exists for the TestTwo()

Comment: This grabs all the lines till the first <summary> section of the file. Assume all Tests above TestTwo, may or maynot have <summary> sections as well...

Comment: Correction: It grabs all the Tests above that contain a <summary> section

Comment: It does extract the output above for the test, for the ones that do have summary. For the ones that don't, the first lines match perfectly but it includes some other tests post "the searched test" which have a summary section. (Considering if TestTwo didn't have a summary section and some of the TestN had)

Comment: try: `grep -oPz '(?s)(?:/*\h*<summary>((?!<summary>).)*</summary>\n)?\[(Fact|Theory)]\n((?!\[(Fact|Theory)]\n).)*TestTwo[^\n]+\n' file.cpp`

Comment: This time <summary> altogether isn't displayed for both cases. In the case where it has a summary section, the correct lines are displayed, and where there isn't, just like the previous output without summary

Comment: I am updating the input string so you're able to test as well..

Comment: I think it is not really a good idea to constantly work on a completely different requirements from what was originally asked in question.  Even starting with `Fact` and `Theory` was a modified requirement.

Comment: Yeah I understand. Really sorry about that. I'm kinda new here.. I have updated the string though. As I said, this isn't a necessity, I was just wondering how to achieve that if I could. You've already helped enough!

Comment: My latest grep command works pretty well. You can see this demo: https://regex101.com/r/bBGVMP/1 and keep changing method names to whatever and you sill find correct match with summary being highlighted.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks alot @anubhava.. And so sorry for the constant modifications. Will keep that in my mind going forward and keep the question detailed from the very beginning. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
output              { output=output ORS $0 }     # if we have something in variable "output" then add current line
/\[Fact]|\[Theory]/ { output=$0 }                # (re)set "output" to current line
/ TestTwo\(/        { if (output)                # if "output" is not empty then ...
                         print output            # print to stdout and ...
                      output=""                  # clear
                    }
' input
```

This generates:

```
[Theory]
[Trait("ab", "cd")]
[Trait("ef", "ghi")]
[InlineData(jkl)]
[InlineData(mnop)]
public async Task TestTwo(string hello)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ tac input|awk '/TestTwo/ {f=1} /\[Theory\]|\[Fact\]/ && f {f=0; print} f{print}'|tac 
[Theory]
[Trait("ab", "cd")]
[Trait("ef", "ghi")]
[InlineData(jkl)]
[InlineData(mnop)]
public async Task TestTwo(string hello)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.